# ViewPageIndicator - What is the use of GoogleMusicAdapter in SampleTabsStyled class?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am using ViewPageIndicator and ActionBarSherlock in my app. I rename SampleTabsStyled  class and use it in my app. Everything is going right. I want to know something

1. Why does it has GoogleMusicAdapter subclass of SampleTabsStyled class?
   2.What is the use of TestFragmentAdapter class? Can i rename it and reuse it?

Answer (score 0):

the GoogleMusicAdapter class just sets different names for the tabs shown in the example, I think it would be clearer if the declaration of the CONTENT array was inside the nested class.

So, you can skip the use of that class and use directly the TestFragmentAdapter as you suggest.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I dont think so. Becuase tabs are named by an array in activity.

Comment: In my view this may contain a list of songs in media files because it is an adapter class.